# Swift generic enums for as TableView data source

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I want to create a UITableViewController that accepts an `enum` as it's data source.
The thing is, I have quite a few `enums` that I want it to be able to handle.

I created a protocol called `TableViewSelectable` and created some `enums` that conform to it like so:

```
protocol TableViewSelectable {

}

enum Genders: Int, TableViewSelectable {
    case male = 0, female

    static let allKeys = [male, female]
    static let allNames = [male.getName, female.getName]

    var getName: String {
        switch self {
        case .male:
            return "Male"
        case .female:
            return "Female"
        }
    }
}

enum Goals: Int, TableViewSelectable {
    case gainMuscleMass, getTrimFit, loseWeight

    static let allKeys = [gainMuscleMass, getTrimFit, loseWeight]
    static let allNames = [gainMuscleMass.getName, getTrimFit.getName, loseWeight.getName]

    var getName: String {
        switch self {
        case .gainMuscleMass:
            return "Gain muscle mass"
        case .getTrimFit:
            return "Get trim & fit"
        case .loseWeight:
            return "Lose weight"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have created an instance variable on my `UITableViewController` like so:

```
class ChoiceListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var data: TableViewSelectable?

}
```

The problem is I have no idea how to go from here.
What I want to have is the option to give that `UITableViewController` any `enum` that conforms to `TableViewSelectable` in order to use as its data source.

I want to access it on the `UITableViewController` like this:

```
final class ChoiceListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var data: TableViewSelectable?


    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    }

}

// MARK: Table View Data Source & Delegate

extension ChoiceListTableViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return data.allKeys.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChoiceTableViewCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = data.allNames[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Help please? :)

Comment: You did something and have no idea where to go from there - then why exactly do you want a table view that accepts enum as data source?

Comment: @mag_zbc because I need a generic tableview that I can launch from anywhere and initialize it with different enums as data source

Comment: So, could add some examples of how the implementation of the table view data source methods shall be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current implementation is that the `allKeys` and `allNames` static properties that you should be using in your `UITableViewDataSource` method are not part of the `TableViewSelectable` protocol, so you cannot access them using the `data` variable.

You should modify your protocol to include these.

```
protocol TableViewSelectable {
    static var allKeys: [TableViewSelectable] {get}
    static var allNames: [String] {get}
}
```

You also need to modify your `enum`s conforming to it accordingly.

```
enum Genders: Int, TableViewSelectable {
    case male = 0, female

    static let allKeys:[TableViewSelectable] = [male, female]
    static let allNames = [male.getName, female.getName]

    var getName: String {
        switch self {
        case .male:
            return "Male"
        case .female:
            return "Female"
        }
    }
}

enum Goals: Int, TableViewSelectable {
    case gainMuscleMass, getTrimFit, loseWeight

    static let allKeys:[TableViewSelectable] = [gainMuscleMass, getTrimFit, loseWeight]
    static let allNames = [gainMuscleMass.getName, getTrimFit.getName, loseWeight.getName]

    var getName: String {
        switch self {
        case .gainMuscleMass:
            return "Gain muscle mass"
        case .getTrimFit:
            return "Get trim & fit"
        case .loseWeight:
            return "Lose weight"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use `data.allKeys` and `data.allNames` to access the corresponding element of these arrays in your data source methods.

```
class ChoiceListTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var data:TableViewSelectable.Type! // make sure that this is actually initialized before accessing it

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.allKeys.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data.allNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you! :)